# Есть ли разница в .aggregate и .agg в pandas? Если да, то какая?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Bogdan\\Desktop\\business-price-indexes-march-2019-quarter-csv.csv")
data=pd.DataFrame(a)
first=data.groupby('Group')['Period'].agg('mean')
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

[В исходнике Pandas метод “agg” объявлен так](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L204):

```
agg = aggregate
```

Т.е. “agg” является ссылкой на “aggregate”.